# Cant load EasyAr scene by LoadSceneAsync

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, scene, easyar

I trying to load scene with EasyAR asynchronously by script b. But its doesnt work.

```
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Scene_name")
```

It works if I try to load scene using

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene_name")
```

The question is: Is there any way to load it async?

Working with c#.

 Test on Android device. 

 Unity 2018.3.12f

 Easy AR ver. 3.0

Thanks!

New code update:

```
  private void WallSceneLoader()
    {
        _loaderGameObject.SetActive(true);
        var asyncScene = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(Constants.Scenes.AR_SCENE);
        asyncScene.allowSceneActivation = false;

        while (asyncScene.progress < 0.9f)
        {
            var progress = Mathf.Clamp01(asyncScene.progress / 0.9f);
            _loaderBar.value = progress;
        }

        Debug.Log("asyncScene.isDone = true");
        asyncScene.allowSceneActivation = true;}
```

The `_loader.gameObject` its just slider with progression bar.

Comment: do you await the first call?

Comment: Can you add more information about what means "it doesn't work". Does it give any errors? 
Do you check the progress on the AsynOperation?

Comment: Please also add more code for context

Comment: @sephiroth no, I dont.

Comment: @cjf93 Its not give any errors. Just cant recognize camera and it's continue working but without easyar.

Comment: @derHugo ok, I updated my post.

Comment: where how is this called?

Comment: @derHugo In another method.  Just `WallSceneLoader(); `

Comment: @AndreyGorlov derHugo's solution is just what you're looking for. You can find more documentation and examples [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-progress.html) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using this `while` loop in a "normal" method you block the thread anyway so you loose the entire advantage of async here.

---

What you rather want to do is use it in a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like it is actually also shown in the example for [`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html)

```
private IEnumerator WallSceneLoader()
{
    _loaderGameObject.SetActive(true);
    var asyncScene = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(Constants.Scenes.AR_SCENE);
    asyncScene.allowSceneActivation = false;

    while (asyncScene.progress < 0.9f)
    {
        var progress = Mathf.Clamp01(asyncScene.progress / 0.9f);
        _loaderBar.value = progress;

        // tells Unity to pause the routine here
        // render the frame and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    Debug.Log("asyncScene.isDone = true");
    asyncScene.allowSceneActivation = true;
}
```

And then use [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) where you want to call it

```
StartCoroutine(WalSceneLoader());
```